# Which values can _MSVC_LANG have?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and my `_MSVC_LANG` is defined as `201402L`, regardless of whether I supply `/std:c++14` as compiler parameter or not.

Does `_MSVC_LANG` have other values in later or earlier versions of visual-c++?

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/12/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-3/) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: /std:c++14 is the default for Update 3, so adding the option does not change anything.  There are no earlier versions that have the macro, we don't have a time machine to guess at later versions.  Just try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to [Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), the `_MSVC_LANG` macro didn't exist (internally they relied on the `__cplusplus` macro containing the equivalent version number).

In Visual Studio's `yvals.h` header, you can see the logic for C++ version macros (this is from Visual Studio 2017 15.3.3):

```
 #ifndef _HAS_CXX17
  #if defined(_MSVC_LANG) && !(defined(__EDG__) && defined(__clang__))  // TRANSITION, VSO#273681
   #if _MSVC_LANG > 201402
    #define _HAS_CXX17  1
   #else /* _MSVC_LANG > 201402 */
    #define _HAS_CXX17  0
   #endif /* _MSVC_LANG > 201402 */
  #else /* _MSVC_LANG etc. */
   #if __cplusplus > 201402
    #define _HAS_CXX17  1
   #else /* __cplusplus > 201402 */
    #define _HAS_CXX17  0
   #endif /* __cplusplus > 201402 */
  #endif /* _MSVC_LANG etc. */
 #endif /* _HAS_CXX17 */
```

The preprocessor definitions `_HAS_CXX17` & `_HAS_CXX14` control the inclusion of STL features.

Answer (score 1):

[Another resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170) lists the possible values for `_MSVC_LANG` as `201402L`, `201703L`, `202002L`, or a `higher unspecified value`, depending on the `/std` switch being used during compilation:

> _MSVC_LANG Defined as an integer literal that specifies the C++ language standard targeted by the compiler. It's set only in code
> compiled as C++. The macro is the integer literal value 201402L by
> default, or when the /std:c++14 compiler option is specified. The
> macro is set to 201703L if the /std:c++17 compiler option is
> specified. The macro is set to 202002L if the /std:c++20 compiler
> option is specified. It's set to a higher, unspecified value when the
> /std:c++latest option is specified. Otherwise, the macro is undefined.
> The _MSVC_LANG macro and /std (Specify language standard version)
> compiler options are available beginning in Visual Studio 2015 Update
> 3.