# How to correctly set _MSVC_LANG value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

As you may know `_MSVC_VALUE` determines whether `_HAS_CXX17` and `_HAS_CXX20` macros are set. Today I tried to compile the following code in Visual Studio 2019 (latest 16.6.4 version):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> _vector = { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::sort(std::execution::par, _vector.begin(), _vector.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it throws errors. For example this one:
`C3083    'execution': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type`

When I looked into the `<execution>` header file I noticed that it doesn't compile because macro `_HAS_CXX17` is set to 0.

```cpp
#if !_HAS_CXX17
#pragma message("The contents of <execution> are available only with C++17 or later.")
#else // ^^^ !_HAS_CXX17 / _HAS_CXX17 vvv
```

So then I looked at the definition of the `_HAS_CXX17` macro which is in the *vcruntime.h* file:

```cpp
#if !defined(_HAS_CXX17) && !defined(_HAS_CXX20)
    #if defined(_MSVC_LANG)
        #define _STL_LANG _MSVC_LANG
    #elif defined(__cplusplus) // ^^^ use _MSVC_LANG / use __cplusplus vvv
        #define _STL_LANG __cplusplus
    #else  // ^^^ use __cplusplus / no C++ support vvv
        #define _STL_LANG 0L
    #endif // ^^^ no C++ support ^^^

    #if _STL_LANG > 201703L
        #define _HAS_CXX17 1
        #define _HAS_CXX20 1
    #elif _STL_LANG > 201402L
        #define _HAS_CXX17 1
        #define _HAS_CXX20 0
    #else // _STL_LANG <= 201402L
        #define _HAS_CXX17 0
        #define _HAS_CXX20 0
    #endif // Use the value of _STL_LANG to define _HAS_CXX17 and _HAS_CXX20

    #undef _STL_LANG
#endif // !defined(_HAS_CXX17) && !defined(_HAS_CXX20)
```

To my surprise the value of `_MSVC_LANG` is set to `201402L`. It should be a lot higher. I set the `-std=c++17` compilation flag like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063791/10732434). Yeah, it's my answer, which proves it worked back in May.

I tried defining the correct value for the macros myself but they are ignored or it throws some other errors:

```cpp
#define _MSVC_LANG 201704L

// same code as before
// result: macro is ignored, no change
```

```cpp
#define _HAS_CXX17 1
#define _HAS_CXX20 1

// same code as before
// result: 250+ errors like this one:
// E0457    "basic_string_view" is not a function or static data member
```

Just before the update I installed a separated version of standard library from [here](http://winlibs.com/). The GCC 10.1.0. version and I put `mingw/bin` on the system path in Windows 10.

I am not aware that installing gcc could break msvc compiler. Then it might be caused by the update of VS 2019 to version 16.6.4?

I also looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639122/which-values-can-msvc-lang-have) but it's not of any help.

- Can anyone report similar problem?
- Does anybody know how to fix this and compile code under C++17 with VS 2019 version 16.6.4?

Comment: You go into the compiler options and you set the C++ language version to C++20. You don't mess with the built-in macros.

Comment: `/std:c++17` … You're trying to use the g++/clang switch for c++17, which isn't valid in MCSV. (unless this was just a typo in your question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future readers:

If you have similar issue, double-check that you are changing configuration that you will run then. In my case I was changing all the settings for *Release* but I tried to run the *Debug* configuration instead and I somehow didn't notice it.

Steps to change the configuration:

- Right click on project
- In the top left corner there is a drop-down menu
- Select the same configuration you are running

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to move to C++20 and the _MSVC_LANG kept on being 201703 (leading to _HAS_CXX20 being 0).
The problem in my case was that the `.vcxproj` file had a language standard 'condition' still being stdcpp17 (while the language standard was correctly at stdcpp20). Removing these lines from the file worked.
See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-studio-wont-compile-with-the-c/10378148

Answer (score 1):

Set the platform to "All Platforms" and then make my changes.

Then they flow through the project correctly.