# Should I cater to MSVC by checking MSVC_LANG?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cross-platform, preprocessor-directive

MSVC does not properly define `__cplusplus`, unless one specifies the `/Z:cplusplus` switch.

Now, in a library I'm maintaining, I have some conditional compilation logic such as:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
etc. etc.
#endif
```

Now - as I intend my code to be portable, and MSVC is the popular compiler on Windows - should I "cater" to it by replacing that condition with:

```
#if (__cplusplus >= 201703L) || (_MSVC_LANG >= 201703L)
etc. etc.
#endif
```

or should I use the standard facility, and expect library users to use `/Z:cplusplus`?

Comment: `_MSVC_LANG` is less reliable than `__cplusplus`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639122/which-values-can-msvc-lang-have

Comment: @273K: I know, but my check involves both.

Comment: What you suggest sounds like a good idea to me.  How many million edits will that entail?  Another, perhaps more future-proof, solution would be to localise that messy test in a single `#include` file and define something in there of your own which you then test inline, as and when needed.  So, for example, `#if (__cplusplus >= 201703L) || (_MSVC_LANG >= 201703L) .. #define einpoklum_cpp_ver 17 .. #endif` and then, where needed, `#if einpoklum_cpp_ver >= 17 ... #endif`.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Well, that would still be about the same number of edits; and would be somewhat opaque/mysterious.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see that it it's necessarily opaque.  Just choose a nice descriptive name for your `#define`(s) and you're golden.  Put it this way, localising that messy test sounds like a sensible move to me.  Suppose you get it wrong and need to change it (or maybe later want to add a second one for C++20 or something).

Comment: Sorry, I can abbreviate that: DRY.  And does your IDE have a 'jump to definition' function?  Visual Studio certainly does.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of __cplusplus, I test the various feature macros,(__cpp_inline_variables as an example). I only use __cplusplus to distinguish C++ from C, not among the various C++ standards.

Comment: Won't they depend on the feature-specific headers which I want to understand whether to include or not?

Comment: He's including `bits/stdc++` :) (sorry, @soronel, I couldn't resist!)

Comment: I use __has_include to check for those. And you can check whether __has_include is supported before actually using it.

Comment: According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170) MSVC supports `__has_include` from VS2017 15.3 onwards.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: So can you edit your answer to present a full example for some specific C++17 feature with an include file?